# Chrome does not keep consistent rem units on zoom-in

Tags: html, css, zooming

I want to make use of `rem` units in CSS, so I set a font-size to my `<html>` tag so I can set child elements with `rem` dimensions. The problem however is that when you zoom in on Chrome, the `font-size` style seems to change relative to zoom level, which causes the dimensions of elements with `rem` units to change relative to the level of zoom. See the example below in Chrome:

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  console.log(getComputedStyle(document.body.parentElement, null).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 7px;
}
body {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.box {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>foo bar baz</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To see the effect, press to run the snippet, then click to view full screen, and zoom out in Chrome. When zoomed out past 75% you'll see that the box does not change size on your screen, while the whole page is supposed to change zoom level.

Also, as you can see in the console, the computed style for `<html>` is `font-size: 12px` when the zoom level is **25%**, which is a direct contradiction to the css styles specified.

This does not happen in Firefox, so I would like to know: how can I use `rem` units while keeping consistent behaviour across browsers when zooming?

Comment: I'm seeing `7px` font size at any zoom level. Could it be a Chrome plugin? Or, try adding a viewport like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your head. Does that fix it?

Comment: That meta tag does not seem to fix it, no. I could try checking what happens in Windows (currently I'm using Linux), but I'm not sure if that'll change anything.

Comment: Hm, I'm on Mac OS 10.14.6 and Chrome 78.0.3904.108. Have you tried incognito mode which would block extensions?

Comment: I just checked and that didn't do anything either; the exact same thing still happens. I'm on Chrome 78.0.3904.108 as well, on Ubuntu 18.04, so the browser version and extensions shouldn't play a role. In fact, when trying it on Chromium 78.0.3904.108 (which I rarely use otherwise), the same thing happens as well. So, no specific config can be affecting it there.

Comment: I was able to reproduce in Chrome by setting a minimum font size. Settings > Appearance > Customize Fonts > Minimum Font Size. Maybe you have that set?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that sounds like a good one to check. But, it does look like my minimum font size is set to 0, so I'm not sure how that would affect my zoom levels.

Comment: I have a very similar problem with `rem` in a linear-gradient background image, where zoom out makes the value smaller in the background image than it is in other contexts, and zoom in makes it larger. This happens not only in Chrome but also in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to simply multiply the original `font-size` by 2, and then divide all `rem` sizes by 2 as well, because then the `font-size` at **50%** will be `7px` again. In other situations, that may not work, but repeating this trick again might fix

The problem **seems** to be that Chrome decides that its rendered font sizes cannot be less than 3px, which means that any font size below 12px will gradually creep towards being rendered at 3px, but will never shrink to smaller than that.

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  console.log(getComputedStyle(document.body.parentElement, null).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.box {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>foo bar baz</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course I'm still interested to see what the actual reasons behind any of this are, and if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe this has something to do with the **Minimum font size** setting in Chrome, under **Customize fonts**.

The default minimum font size is `6px`. So **90%** of **7** is **6.3**, whereas **80%** of **7** is **5.6**, which is the point at which the console logged value begins to change. If you change the root font size in your HTML to `16px`, you won't see that same phenomenon again until you get to **33%** zoom, because **33%** of **16** is **5.28**, which falls below the minimum font size. Try changing the minimum font size to something larger than `6px` (like, say, `12px`) and you'll see this phenomenon occurs even earlier when you begin to zoom out, and it seems to always be at the point where the font-size would theoretically become smaller than what the browser has set as its minimum font size. However, reducing the minimum font size to anything below **6** seems to have no effect on anything.

I'm not sure why this occurs, but it is interesting.